# 360 degree view using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am getting video frame from 4 different cams and I am stitching them in single frame using below code, I want to stitch them in 360 degree view, 
Is it possible to do in openCV ? if yes could some one guide me.

```
capture >> frame;
capture1 >> frame1;
capture2 >> frame2;
capture3 >> frame3;

frame.copyTo(canvas(Rect(0,0,frame.cols,frame.rows )));
frame1.copyTo(canvas(Rect(frame.cols,0,frame1.cols,frame1.rows )));
frame2.copyTo(canvas(Rect(0,frame.rows,frame2.cols,frame2.rows )));
frame3.copyTo(canvas(Rect(frame2.cols,frame1.rows,frame3.cols,frame3.rows )));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've already looked at the API that Opencv has implemented for stitching images at: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html

There are also some tutorials on panaroma stitching in Python on the popular pyimagesearch site: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/

In general, the solution involves using a feature detector and descriptor like SIFT, SURF, ORB that is scale/rotation invariant and then use a descriptor matcher like BFmatcher on opencv to find the matches. You would then have to apply geometric transformations like the affine transformations on the image in order to overlay the two images.